# Using Python, how can I obtain the running process and the exe name for that process?

Tags: python, windows, process

Suppose that I have an exe running and its name is `myexe.exe`. On Windows, I can see the process for `myexe.exe` in Process Explorer. Using Python, how can I obtain the process ID of `myexe.exe` and shut it down?

Comment: Is it from the current process or from the python shell? You can get the latter from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python, or how to kill a process from python : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214773/kill-process-with-python

Comment: Your question has been answered here. Please don't double post.
[How can I find a process by name and kill using ctypes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980246/how-can-i-find-a-process-by-name-and-kill-using-ctypes). Remember, every time you double-post, Jon Skeet kills a kitten. Please, think of the kittens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via wmi service, if you use the [wmi](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) (Windows Management Instrumentation module). Look here for the [examples](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html) to get the process name and to terminate using the process id.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it on windows is to use PyWin32 ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32 )

Look at the following code sample: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2007-10/msg00717.html

It might be exactly what you need.

Comment: actually, I'm looking forward to a way using ctyps not 3rd-party modules.