# How to stop all child processes spawnedby a single script using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, multiprocessing

I need to run a `unittest` on part of my package, and the best thing for me to do this is to control launching it and then killing all processes spawned by `multiprocessing` module.

Here is what I'm talking about:

#### test.py

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start_consumers(conf, worker_count=5):
    manager = WorkerManager(conf, worker_count)
    manager.start()


class WorkerManager():
    def __init__(self, conf, worker_count=5):
        self.workers = []
        for num in range(worker_count):
            self.workers.append(WorkHandler(conf))

    def start(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.daemon = True
            worker.start()

        print 'started'
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()

class WorkHandler(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, conf, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.conf = conf
        self.name = str(random.randint(0,100))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print self.conf['foo'], self.name
            time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = {'foo': 'bar'}
    start_consumers(conf)
```

Now if I run this test from linux terminal, I can see print statements, also if i do:
`ps aux | grep python` I see all child processes where spawned:

```
sergey    4081  0.0  0.1  71684 13164 pts/3    S+   08:58   0:00 python
sergey    4108  0.3  0.0  39092  6472 pts/3    S+   08:59   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4109  0.0  0.0  39092  4576 pts/3    S+   08:59   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4110  0.0  0.0  39092  4568 pts/3    S+   08:59   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4111  0.0  0.0  39092  4576 pts/3    S+   08:59   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4112  0.0  0.0  39092  4584 pts/3    S+   08:59   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4113  0.0  0.0  39092  4580 pts/3    S+   08:59   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4115  0.0  0.0  13588   944 pts/7    S+   08:59   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

Now if I'm trying to run the same `test.py` with `subprocess` everything works fine up to the point until I need to kill them all:

```
>>> import subprocess as s
>>> p = s.Popen(['python', 'test.py'], stdout=s.PIPE)
```

#### The Question:

What is the most elegant way to do something with this variable `p` in order to achieve similar behaviour when I press `Ctrl+C` in terminal? 
In other words I want to achive a result similar to `pkill -f "test.py"`

### UPDATE:

`p.kill()` or `p.terminate()` doesn't do what I need:

Here is the result after I do eather of them:

```
sergey    4438  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/3    Z+   09:16   0:00 [python] <defunct>
sergey    4439  0.0  0.0  39092  4572 pts/3    S+   09:16   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4440  0.0  0.0  39092  4568 pts/3    S+   09:16   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4441  0.0  0.0  39092  4576 pts/3    S+   09:16   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4442  0.0  0.0  39092  4580 pts/3    S+   09:16   0:00 python test.py
sergey    4443  0.0  0.0  39092  4580 pts/3    S+   09:16   0:00 python test.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is the `subprocess.terminate()` and `subprocess.kill()` methods of [subprocess objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

You will likely have to combine that with a method registered with [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) that iterates across your list of subprocesses and terminates them. EX:

```
def terminate_children(children):
    for process in children:
        process.terminate()

...
# Somewhere else in your code
children = [s.Popen(['python', 'test.py'], stdout=s.PIPE) for i in range(number_processes)] # Spools up number_processes child processes
atexit.register(terminate_children, children) # where children is a list of subprocesses
```

This will terminate all child processes gracefully when you terminate the parent process gracefully.

If you're trying to kill the processes from a completely separate script with no direct reference to the child code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214773/kill-process-with-python). You'll basically want to look at the python `os` [process management methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-management)

Comment: Not quiet sure I understand where it needs to go? The goal is to not change the source code and to create some kind of a clean up process, but be able to terminate them all from a separate code.

Comment: I assume you're spooling up you subprocesses somewhere correct? The ``atexit`` code would go wherever that's happening. Simply store a list of the ``p`` objects you're creating, and pass them as the children parameter in my example. I'll edit it to make that more clear.

Comment: No it's not what I want, your code will spwn `N` number of processes and each of them will spanw `N` number of subprocesses

Comment: See the link I posted at the end. If neither of those are still what you want, you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: I successfuly used your approach cleaning up too many communicating subprocesseses which causes CPU overload and hangs MAC OS.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a new session and kill all descendant processes using `os.killpg()`:

```
import os
import signal
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen('python test.py', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
# ... later
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM) # send signal to the process group
```

See [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279).