# Python - How to terminate a subprocess when running an opened gnome-terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I will use `gedit` just as an example.
I wanted it to open `gedit` via another terminal and then close it by killing the terminal:

```
import subprocess
import time

process = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "gedit"])
time.sleep(3)
process.terminate()
```

The problem is that the terminal won't be killed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using killing by the process ID rather than the generic process name?

Example: 
[kill process with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214773/kill-process-with-python)

Comment: I tried doing `os.kill(int(proc.pid), signal.SIGTERM)` but it still didn't work.